# The request its too long on mobile

Tags: asp.net, mobile, web-applications

hi i'm developing a web app on asp.net and i'm making some testing on mobile devices and i'm getting the message "it cannot show the page due the request it's too long" when i send my completed form.
[image]

making tries on desktop this problem doesn't appears, the problem it´s just appearing in mobile devices, i tried on google chrome and Microsoft edge but there's no difference.

looking around for the origin of this message i found that it's a memory problem, i tried some solutions like `<serverRuntime>` configuration in the `web.config` but apparently it doesn't work, inclusive i made some configuration on `<requestlimits>` on the iis server and it does't work neither for some more information i send between **4 and 16 images** at onece in addition of some other plain text info.

Comment: Are you making heavy use of viewstate? You could consider disable of viewstate say for a girdview, or other types of data bound controls. (or move viewstate stuff to session() based).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you making heavy use of viewstate? You could consider disable of viewstate say for a girdview, or other types of data bound controls. (or move viewstate stuff to session() based)

Another thing to look at is how you displaying the images.

If your are streaming the images (base64)? Then when the user hits a button, then ALL OF those images are posted back to the server. This can often result in a payload that is too large.

So, if you have images, then use a image control, and if you streaming the images as xbase64 images, then you need to create + adopt a image handler.

So, without more details, we all are in the dark, but giving some love and care to the size of viewstate may well fix this issue for you.

Comment: hi, you´re right about the streaming images, now on mobile devices the post works normal